# How to create an API to send files to a server / Swift

Tags: javascript, swift, server

I need to be able to pick certain files from my phone and send it to a server. The server does not have an API yet as I'm still working on it. I was wondering what would be the best way of implementing it. I was thinking about picking the files, converting it to Data and then sending it? And then converting back on a server? Or am I saying nonsense because I'm really new to this.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the data you want to send. If you are going to send binary data, images, videos, send it as such, if you are able to easily convert it back on the server. If you want to send specific data that has key/value pairs, specific for some entities you are sending, easiest way is to use JSON. Convert the object of entity to JSON, send it to the server, get what you need from it on the server. You didn't specify the language for server (or is it JS?) so it's hard to specify it more precisely